# Why did Gödel name his constructible universe $L$?

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview

It seems like Gödel didn't use the letter $L$ for his model before his book "The Consistency of the Axiom of Choice and of the Generalized Continuum-Hypothesis with the Axioms of Set Theory", which is probably the first place it got used.

Do anyone of you know why he used the letter $L$? It does seem like a bit ad hoc in the book, where he names some functions $J_i$, then some other functions $K_i$ and then ends up defining $L$. But why $J_i$ then?

(I'm sorry if this is not suited for MO)

Comment: the sequence $J,K,L,\ldots$ seems quite natural to me, I would not attach any meaning to it

Comment: A lot of things are ad hoc, and they become standard.

Comment: Perhaps this somehow another instance of the phenomenon whereby Grothendieck used G and K (the first and last letters of his name) for the covariant and contravariant versions of K-theory.

Comment: Maybe it is a universe you wouldn't want to live in, a bloody 'ell.

Comment: @M.Logic Could you provide a reference or citation for Gödel's believing that $V=L$ should be true?  I had heard the opposite.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Neglect that since it's also hearsay...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I heard from [Kai Hauser](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~hauser/) that the letter $L$ comes from "**law**", and it is because the model is constructed using some laws.

Comment: Only Gödel was Austrian and his work in german. The german word for law is "Gesetz" so that by your logic $L$ should have been named $G$.

Comment: Let me mention at least that Kai Hauser also is German.

Comment: @JohannesHahn If Gödel's paper was in German, then I could accept your remark, but the fact is that his paper is in English.

Comment: @JohannesHahn It might be considered inappropriate for someone whose name begins with G to name his invention G.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Accept my apology. I actually didn't know Gödel switched to english. I was under the impression all his work was in german just like "Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme"

Comment: If this were the explanation, one would expect the word “law” to appear somewhere in Godel’s writing on the subject — does it?

Answer (score 24):

So far as I know, there are four interpretations why Gödel uses $\mathrm{L}$ to denote the constructible universe.

(1) By Paul Bernays (see page 64 in [*Halbeisen 2017*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078YGW67G)), Gödel originally used the old German script [image: capital C in old German script] to denote the constructible universe, where [image] is a capital $\mathrm{C}$. Although the appearance of [image: capital C in old German script] is very like the German script $\mathfrak{L}$ for $\mathrm{L}$, in fact it's one kind of the German script $\mathfrak{C}$ for $\mathrm{C}$. Furthermore Bernay's words don't show why Gödel uses $\mathrm{L}$ to denote constructible universe in [*1940*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691079271/consistency-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-am-3-volume-3) (in fact he had introduced the constructible universe in [*1938*](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.24.12.556) which is a proceeding paper). So I don't think Bernays' interpretation is suitable (as desired).

(2) By Kai Hauser, the letter $\mathrm{L}$ comes from "law" since the model is constructed using some laws. But in [*1940*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691079271/consistency-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-am-3-volume-3), Gödel didn't mention any law and the word "law" at all. Furthermore, if so, any other model should be named $\mathrm{L}$ since they are also constructed using some other laws. So I don't think Hauser's interpretation is suitable either.

(3) By someone (I don't remember who said this first), since von Neumann's universe is the first model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ which is denoted by $\mathrm{V}$ and the constructible universe may be the second model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, to distinguish from and show relations to $\mathrm{V}$, Gödel extends the angle of $\mathrm{V}$ to 90，rotates it down to the horizontal line, and then makes it become $\mathrm{L}$. Of course, it is a joke, and can't be suitable either.

(4) In my opinion, *the only suitable interpretation for Gödel's using $\mathrm{L}$ to denote the constructible universe is that $\mathrm{L}$ is after $\mathrm{J,K}$ in order* since Gödel defines the constructible universe $\mathrm{L}$ after defining some functions $\mathrm{J}_\mathrm{i}$ and $\mathrm{K}_\mathrm{i}$ for which beginning with $\mathrm{J}$ is possibly because almost all the letters before $\mathrm{J}$ have been used before introducing the constructible universe in [*1940*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691079271/consistency-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-am-3-volume-3) (and in particular he uses $\mathfrak{Cls}(\mathrm{A})$ related to $\mathfrak{C}$ for $\mathrm{C}$ to denote that $\mathrm{A}$ is a class and $\mathrm{Y}\,\mathfrak{Con}\,\mathrm{X}$ to denote that $\mathrm{Y}$ is connex in $\mathrm{X}$). In fact in [*1940*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691079271/consistency-of-the-continuum-hypothesis-am-3-volume-3), Gödel's usages of many symbols are very random, for example he uses $\mathfrak{A}$ to denote some *operation* and $\mathfrak{B}$ to denote some *notion* without any sufficient considerations.

---

By the way, there are also four interpretations why people use $\mathrm{V}$ to denote the cumulative universe of all sets, or the class of all sets.

(1) Peano used uses $\mathrm{V}$ for "verum", i.e., the propositional truth constant for true, and its upside down form $\Lambda$ for "falsum", i.e., the dual propositional false constant, on page VIII in [*1889*](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog). He furthermore uses $\mathrm{V}$ to denote the class of all individuals, and $\Lambda$ to denote the class containing no individuals on page XI in [*1889*](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) in Latin. The following words improved from [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244837/why-did-g%C3%B6del-name-his-constructible-universe-l#comment1036517_404554) of @EmilJeřábek may show why Peano made such uses.

> On page VIII, Peano uses $\mathrm{V}$ for "verum", i.e., the propositional truth constant for true (that would nowadays be denoted $\top$ or 1), and its upside down form $\Lambda$ for "falsum", i.e., the dual propositional false constant (that would nowadays be denoted $\bot$ or 0), and also, $-$, $\cap$, $\cup$ (that would nowadays be denoted  $\neg$, $\wedge$, $\vee$) for the propositional connectives. Then, on pages X–XI, he uses the same symbols $-$, $\cap$, $\cup$ to denote the corresponding operations on classes, and thus $\mathrm{V}$, $\Lambda$ becomes respectively the class of all individuals and the class containing no individuals.

(2) Whitehead and Rusell used $\mathrm{V}$ to denote the class of all objects, which is defined as $\mathrm{V}=\{x\mid x=x\}$ in modern notations, on page 229 in [*1910*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/168422330X). Whitehead and Rusell also used $\Lambda$ to denote the null class on page 229 in [*1910*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/168422330X). The following words improved from comments of @Goldstern may show why they made such uses.

> $\mathrm{V}=\{x\mid x=x\}$, i.e., $\mathrm{V}=\{x\mid$ $x=x$ is true (verum)$\}$.

After them, people began to use $\mathrm{V}$ to denote the class of all individuals (objects). And nowadays there may be two more interpretations. While I don't know who gave those first.

(3) $\mathrm{V}$ is the v in von Neumann. This is because the cumulative universe is also called von Neumann universe which was first claimed by Gregory H. Moore in [*1982*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486488411) because existence and uniqueness of the general transfinite recursive definition of sets was demonstrated by von Neumann for both Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory in [*1928*](http://bbi-math.narod.ru/newmann/newmann.html) and his own set theory on pages 745–752 in [*1928a*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01171122). While in fact the first publication of the von Neumann universe was by Ernst Zermelo in [*1930*](https://doi.org/10.4064/fm-16-1-29-47). Furthermore, the $\mathrm{V}$ notation was not used by von Neumann in his 1920s papers.

(4) $\mathrm{V}$ is the shape of the picture of the cumulative universe.

Comment: What about the possibility that $L$ comes before $M$, as appropriate for something smaller than the usual models? Or perhaps it is “leicht”, lightweight?

Comment: @MattF. Your interpretation seems to be imaginational.

Comment: Peano’s notation at least makes perfect sense: on p. viii, he uses V for “verum”, i.e., the propositional truth constant for true (that would nowadays be denoted $\top$ or $1$), and its upside down form Λ for the dual propositional constant “falsum” (i.e., $\bot$ or $0$). Also, $-$, $\cap$, $\cup$ denote the propositional connectives we write as $\neg$, $\land$, $\lor$. Then, on pp. x–xi, he uses the same symbols ($-$, $\cap$, $\cup$, V, Λ) to denote the corresponding operations on classes: thus, V becomes the class of all objects, $\cap$ is intersection, etc.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, you are right. But this explains no on why at first V is used to denote the class of all sets...

Comment: How does it not explain that? V is used to denote the class of all objects because in general, class operations are denoted by the same symbols as the corresponding connectives. This is just a special case with a nullary connective.

Comment: In axiomatic set theory, objects = sets.

Comment: You are mistaken. This is standard basic logic terminology. Objects (= individuals, which is actually how Peano calls them) are elements of the domain of discourse. For axiomatic theories of sets such as ZF, these are sets, not classes or anything else.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek But it is not a good use...

Comment: I fail to see how your opinion on what is good or bad use is relevant to the question how the terminology and notation emerged. But anyway, this does not matter the slightest. If you do not want to call the elements of the domain of discourse *objects* or *individuals*, that’s fine: call them by whatever word you prefer instead, say *crocodiles*. Then Peano’s usage explains why V denotes the class of all crocodiles, and in axiomatic set theory, crocodiles = sets.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I mean what's the relation of V (a shorthand for the latin word verum) and the class of all individuals (if they are equal to sets)? It seems that there is no obvious and direct way to explain it.

Comment: @M.Logic Verum is the predicate true on all objects. So if you are considering classes singled out by predicates, the predicate Verum singles out the class of all objects.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It's a little far-fetched.

Comment: @M.Logic Do you find it far-fetched enough to undermine the version of emergence of the notation being considered?

Comment: Wasn't V the initial letter of 'universe' in Latin, before the letter U was invented? V for VNIVERSVM?

Comment: @bof Latin letters have become the same as nowdays since the 11th century.

Comment: Rephrasing EmilJeřábek's and  მამუკაჯიბლაძე's comments:   $V=\{x: v\}$, where $v$ abbreviates "verum". That looks right.

Comment: I don't see anything far-fetched about the "$V=\{x:$ v(erum)$\}$" explanation; in fact, that's what I was taught if I remember correctly. I personally think that's the most plausible option, for what it's worth.

Comment: 35th version of this question.